# Ruby linked list, append and prepend methods

Tags: ruby, linked-list

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head 

  def initialize
    @head = nil 
  end

  def append(data)
    @head = Node.new(data)
  end 

  def prepend(data)
    current = Node.new(data)
    current.next = @head 
    @head = current 
  end 
end

test = LinkedList.new
test.prepend(5)
test.prepend(2)
test.prepend(9)
test.append(111)
test.append(222)
```

I'm having trouble learning how to point to new values, and how the pointers change when new values are added. When you use prepend @head equals your new nodes pointer. When you add a second value with prepend, @head now equals that nodes pointer. How does this work? How does the first nodes pointer become nil?

```
def prepend(data)
  current = Node.new(data)
  current.next = @head 
  @head = current 
end
```

My append method will create a new node, but when I try to use append a second time it just overwrites the first. I don't understand how in prepend it adds a new node each time but in append it overwrites the first every time it's called.

```
def append(data)
  @head = Node.new(data)
end
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code. Mainly, you don't want to indent `class LinkedList`.

Comment: I think you are not updating the next of previous node in which you are going to append the new node.

Comment: “I don’t understand” is a statement, not a question. What is your question?

Comment: Cary, isn't everything after the class supposed to be indented with two spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that `@head` is the first element in the linked list. The problem is that `@head` is not sufficient for appending a node, because the logic of `prepend` should be: "`last` element links to the prepended node, the prepended node becomes the new `last` element".

That's why the logic of `LinkedList` transforms into:

```
class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head, :tail

  def initialize
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
  end

  def append(data)
    node = Node.new(data)

    if empty?
      @head = @tail = node
    else
      @tail.next = node
      @tail = node
    end
  end

  def prepend(data)
    node = Node.new(data)

    if empty?
      @head = @tail = node
    else
      node.next = @head
      @head = node
    end
  end

  def empty?
    @head.nil? && @tail.nil?
  end

  def each
    node = @head

    loop do
      break unless node
      yield node
      node = node.next
    end
  end
end
```

Since an empty list is initialized, `@tail` and `@head` need to be assigned to the first appended/prepended node. `each` method is just for convenient printing of the results:

```
test = LinkedList.new
test.prepend(5)
test.prepend(2)
test.prepend(9)
test.append(111)
test.append(222)

test.each { |node| puts node.data }
```

Note, that `append` and `prepend` methods are pretty much the same and can be refactored by removing the duplicated code using `Ruby` blocks.